How to show unused warning like Scaffold.innerPadding not being used?
Android Studio shows warning When the innerPadding of Scaffold is not used:
Scaffod { innerPadding ->  // <---- it's not used
}

I want to implement a similar widget, how can I warn user when my innerPadding is not used? Or maybe need a @SuppressLint("UnusedMyParameter") to suppress it.
I don't find anything special in the source code of Scaffold, how does it do this?

I unfortunately can't provide a complete answer right now. But in order to write your own Linting Rule, you can follow the Android Lint Check Guide.
A lint rule consists of the following elements:

A Detector class where you specify the issues, warning messages and in which cases to report a certain issue
A Registry class where you register all your issues
A file named com.android.tools.lint.client.api.IssueRegistry that you place under res/META-INF/services to publish your Registry class

You will need to add the following two dependencies:
implementation group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-api', version: '31.6.0'
implementation group: 'com.android.tools.lint', name: 'lint-checks', version: '31.6.0'

Then, you can create a Detector class like this:
class SdCardDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {

    companion object Issues {

        // specify an Issue
        @JvmField
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
            id = "SdCardPath",
            briefDescription = "Hardcoded reference to `/sdcard`",
            explanation = """
                Your code should not reference the `/sdcard` path directly""",
            moreInfo = "https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#filesExternal",
            category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
            severity = Severity.ERROR,
            androidSpecific = true,
            implementation = Implementation(
                SdCardDetector::class.java,
                Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE
            )
        )
    }

    // specify on which places this issue should be reported
    override fun run(context: Context) {
        context.report(ISSUE, Location.create(context.file),
            "I complain a lot")
    }
}

Your Registry class could look similar to this:
class SampleIssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
    override val issues = listOf(SdCardDetector.ISSUE)  // register Issue here

    override val api: Int
    get() = CURRENT_API

    override val minApi: Int
    get() = 8

    // Requires lint API 30.0+; if you're still building for something
    // older, just remove this property.
    override val vendor: Vendor = Vendor(
        vendorName = "Android Open Source Project",
        feedbackUrl = "https://com.example.lint.blah.blah",
        contact = "author@com.example.lint"
    )
}

Finally, the com.android.tools.lint.client.api.IssueRegistry will point to your Registry class:
com.my.example.SampleIssueRegistry

Please note I am not able to test this right now. Please consult the documentation for a full guide or check the official implementation of the ScaffoldPaddingDetector.
